# C# Method Overloading - 2 methods with similar parameters

Tags: c#, methods, overloading

I have two methods that have similar input parameter types, but the parameters themselves are different and used to build an SQL statement within the method.

C# doesn't like this - "Type Database already defines a member called 'DatabaseSearch' with the same parameter types."

As a newbie, this sounds to me like I'm structuring the class or methods wrong?

Should I perhaps be building the SQL statement outside the method and passing it and its parameters in?

```
 // Surname ONLY
    public void DatabaseSearch(DataGrid DataGrid, string surname)
    {

        string database_file_path = @"Data Source=.\MemberDB.db";

        string sqlCmd = "Select * FROM Members WHERE Surname = @surname";

        using (var con = new SQLiteConnection(database_file_path))
        {
            using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(con))
            {
                con.Open();

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", surname);

                cmd.CommandText = sqlCmd;

                var dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
                var dt = new DataTable("Members");
                dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
                DataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
                dataAdapter.Update(dt);
            }
        }

    }


 // Firstname ONLY
    public void DatabaseSearch(DataGrid DataGrid, string firstname)
    {

        string database_file_path = @"Data Source=.\MemberDB.db";

        string sqlCmd = "Select * FROM Members WHERE FirstName = @firstname";

        using (var con = new SQLiteConnection(database_file_path))
        {
            using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(con))
            {
                con.Open();

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstname", firstname);

                cmd.CommandText = sqlCmd;

                var dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
                var dt = new DataTable("Members");
                dataAdapter.Fill(dt);
                DataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
                dataAdapter.Update(dt);
            }
        }

    }
```

Summary:

How do you have two overloaded methods with the same types of parameters?

```
 public void myMethod( int one, string one){
 ....some stuff done...
}

 public void myMethod( int two, string two){
 ....different stuff done...
}
```

Comment: Overloading only works on the types of the parameters - the names mean nothing when it comes to overloading.

Comment: Change your method names to be more specific. i.e. `public void SearchFirstName` and `public void SearchLastName`

Comment: It's also a bad idea to pass your UI into a DB call like that. Keep the two separate and use the `DataTable` to pass the data.

Comment: Change your method names as 'SearchByFirstName' and 'SearchByLastName'.the reason is you can't have two or more similar method signatures in same class.i also recommend if you could follow the oop concepts which decouples the operational code from UI

Comment: No, the paramteters are not similar but the same. An int is an int and a string is astring. The term to look for is 'signatur'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either change the method name or change the order of the parameters. The first approach is better.

```cs
 public void DatabaseSearchByFirstName(int one, string one){
 // ...some stuff done...
}

 public void DatabaseSearchBySurName(int two, string two){
 // ...different stuff done...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, obviously it can't be done the way I want it and the best solution is to just have two differently named methods. Changing the order of the parameters is a nice idea but would be confusing.